# Cannot deselect tableView row after reloading section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am implementing a sectioned tableView that expands section rows when you click on the section header. It works for the most part, but when you select a row, collapse the section, then expand the section, you cannot de select the previously selected row. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Another thing is the debugger is printing out `[Assert] Unable to determine new global row index for preReloadFirstVisibleRow (0)` which I've never seen before or know if it's related to the issue. I put breakpoints in the `didDeselect` and `didSelect` functions, and everything hits as expected until the situation I explained above

```
@objc func headerPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if (!tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked) {
        tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked = true
    } else {
        tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked = false
    }
    let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: sender.tag)
    tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableDataSource.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableDataSource[section][0].clicked ? tableDataSource[section].count : 0
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ModifierCell") as? ModifierCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
    let mod = tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.modNameLabel.text = mod.mod.id!
    cell.setSelected(mod.selected, animated: true)
    cell.checkImage.image = mod.selected ? UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle") : UIImage(systemName: "circle")
    
    return cell
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.setSelected(tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected, animated: false)
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ModifierCell
    cell.checkImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected = true 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ModifierCell
    cell.checkImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
    tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected = false
}

// .....

struct tableElement {
    var mod: Modifier
    var clicked = false
    var selected = false
}
```

Comment: You cannot deselect, but the didDeselectRowAt delegate is called ? Did you try to reload  the full tablein deselect, at least to see if it works.  What is the content of sender.tag when you pressed ?  Note, you could siplify your functionalists as follows:   @objc func headerPressed(sender: UIButton){
    tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked.toggle()
    let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: sender.tag)
    tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)
}

Comment: the didDeselectRowAt delegate is called only when you select, then deselect, but if you select, collapse the row, then expand, the cell you selected appears selected, but cannot be deselected, and when trying to deselect a row, the didDeselectRowAt function is not called

Comment: sender.tag is the section that was clicked to expand

Comment: @NoahIarrobino - are you allowing multiple selections, or just single selections? If a row is selected in a section you want to collapse, do you want it to remain selected when that section is expanded?

Comment: I allow multiple selections, yes I want a selected cell to remain selected when collapsed, and it does. The problem is you cannot deselect that cell if it has been selected, collapsed, then expanded. You should be able to deselect that cell even after expanding it

Comment: In your `didSelectRow` and `didDeselectRow`, you could try updating the data source and then reloading the updated row: `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath])`

Comment: sender.tag is the section that was clicked to expand: yes, I understood this. But what is the value when deselect doesn't work ? Is it -1 by any chance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing some information from your actual setup, but this *should* fix the issue...

Replace your `willDisplay cell` function with this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
    //cell.setSelected(tableDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected, animated: false)
}
```